# log4j with an elastic beanstalk cluster

Tags: java, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I managed it to log my application with apache commons logging via log4j.

Now I can write my logfiles i.e. to /var/log/whatever. My question is, what if the beanstalk scales up? Then I have multiple logfiles. Lets say I have a 100 instances then I have 100 logfiles. And what happens to my logfiles, when the beanstalk scales down again?

Is there a soultion, that I dont need to download each logfile from each node, having them on one place? On an S3 i.e.?

** Edit **

I figured out a way to save the logfiles of each instance on a S3 instance. But that doesn't seem like a good solution, because if I have to search for something, it's pretty bad to search through the logs of 100 instances.

Any idea how to get them all together?

Comment: Please have a look into [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=263857)

Comment: Thank you, that was helping.

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel that this might help others, I can add an answer, so people with a similar problem might benefit of it...

Comment: I had to update the question :(

Comment: According comment, provide by @Viccari, you may configure `log4j.properties` for each instance. And you may aggregate all logs do with `log4j` `SimpleScoketServer`, which I recently described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15382152/655756) thread.