# Easiest way to send files to a server

Tags: java, file-upload

I have a Java desktop application that can generate logs. **I would like to send those logs to a remote server**.

What is the correct way of doing that? via **FTP**? writing a small **java server** and sending it with a socket? posting the contents to a **PHP form**?

If using FTP, is it secure? I mean, is it possible to allow uploads but also protect files from being deleted or renamed?

Comment: When and how often should the logs be uploaded? Every hour, once a day, once a week?

Comment: @user714965 Just in case an error is found, so once a week or so (we are in beta :P). The logs should be uploaded at application start (after a crash).

Comment: Have you considered the option of emailing the logs in case of an error? Most logging libraries provide the setting

Comment: @VarunAchar If you think it is a good idea, I will consider it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emailing the log file is also another option. This gives you the option of sending the log to a list of people right on their emails in case you need to perform an action immediately based on the error.

For log4j check this link:

http://www.codereye.com/2009/02/sending-email-alerts-with-log4j.html

Basic gist is is :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, a, email
log4j.appender.a=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.a.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.a.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{1}]: %m%n
log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=10
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=mysmtp.mailserver.net
log4j.appender.email.From=admin@mycompany.com
log4j.appender.email.To=me@mycompany.com
log4j.appender.email.Subject=My Module Error
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Also check the [AsynAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.html) for sending emails asynchronously so that current thread isn't blocked for the email to be sent.

Comment: thanks, I think I will email the logs, I'm not sure if I will use log4j because I don't want to send all the logs but I didn't mention that on the question.

Comment: You can specify the logger level. If a logging event of that level is encountered an email will be sent. You could also specify it for only a package if you want to fine tune it further.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case I would recommend using `log4j`'s [SimpleSocketServer](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SimpleSocketServer.html).

In your server you can just start server with the following parameters:

```
java -cp log4j.jar org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer 4712
```

Here is sample `log4j.properties` for the server:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Here is sample `log4j.properties` for client:

```
log4j.appender.SERVER=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.SERVER.Port=4712
log4j.appender.SERVER.RemoteHost=loghost
log4j.appender.SERVER.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

The only note, is that you can't set some sort of authentication with capabilities of `SimpleSocketServer` only. You can only use some other ways to achieve that, f.e. SSH-tunnel.

Comment: is it possible not to send all logs? I would like to decide when a log should be sent or not.

Comment: Yes, sure. You may specify `category`, `level` and so on particularly for `SERVER` appender. You may even create your own `level` if it is necessary. This approach will be helpful in case if you would like to aggregate some critical logs from several clients. And BTW, on server you may use not only `ConsoleAppender`, but also `SMTPAppender`, which @Varun Achar suggests

Comment: thanks for the answer, I prefer the email solution as I don't have to touch the server but +1 anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Yes... Log4J is very useful for logging mechanism in your application.

And for sending data to the server, its become very easy using client socket - server socket.

There are very useful methods for sending your data from client to server and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @VarunAchar I've decided to send the logs via email. But instead of using log4j (it is a good idea to use it, but in my case I do not need such a complete solution) I've used my own method to send an email with some attachments:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", from); //such as abc@gmail.com
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);   //use smtp.gmail.com for Google
properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from); //such as abc@gmail.com
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port); //use 465 for Google's SMTP server
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port); //use 465 for Google's SMTP server
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

Authenticator mailAuthenticator = new MailAuthenticator(from,"mypassword");
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,mailAuthenticator);
Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);

message.setFrom(fromAddress);
message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
//you can use RecipientTypes such as
//RecipientType.TO
//RecipientType.BCC
//RecipientType.CC
//RecipientType.NEWSGROUPS
message.setSubject(subject);

// Create the message part 
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

// Some text
messageBodyPart.setText(text);

// Attachments
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
// Attach error.log
File f = new File(ruta+"error.log");
if (f.exists()) {
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    String filename = ruta+"error.log";
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

// repeat with more attachments if needed

// Fill email content
message.setContent(multipart);

Transport.send(message);
```

It uses [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)
The original code was found here: http://tunatore.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/how-to-send-an-e-mail-using-java-mail-api-swing-desktop-application-using-googles-smtp-example/ 
And the attachment part was here: http://www.roseindia.net/javamail/SendAttachment.shtml